# Are casts and overflows well-defined for numpy signed integer types?

Tags: python, numpy, casting, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow

On my machine, I can observe the following behavior for `numpy`’s integer data types:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.uint8(-1)
255
>>> numpy.int8(128)
-128
>>> numpy.int8(-129)
127
>>> numpy.int8(127) + numpy.int8(1)
# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in byte_scalars
-128
>>> numpy.int8(-128) - numpy.int8(1)
# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in byte_scalars
127
```

So in all cases, when creating a value of a given type, the input overflows or underflows by wrapping around to the other end of the range of representable values (without a warning), as for unsigned integers. When an overflow or underflow occurs during an operation like addition, the behavior is the same, but a `RuntimeWarning` is emitted.

Now, my question is whether this behavior can be relied on, or whether it can vary depending on the underlying C compiler, since signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C. The only relevant part of `numpy`’s documentation which I could find is [this section on overflow errors](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors), which does give an example involving a signed integer type, but does not explicitly specify what the rules are for casts and overflows and whether the behavior can be expected to be the same across all platforms.

Comment: I just saw another SO question which pointed out that the over/under flow warnings work for `np.int8` objects but not for `np.array(..., 'int8')` arrays.  Because of implementation details, checking for such conditions with whole arrays (as opposed to just one value) is impractical.

Comment: As an addendum, I opened a [corresponding bug report for `numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17982) since `numpy` does not seem to document its behavior or guarantees concerning these cases.